# How can I tell boost cron run to delete a file

Tags: 7, cron, caching

If I have a custom module that maybe adds some fields, or reorders some data which is to be shown in the frontend: How do I tell boost, that the cached files should be deleted on the next cron run after I've made some changes?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set a flag which indicates that new fields are added. Can be a `variable_set()` or something similar thats stores values in DB whenever new fields are added.

In your `hook_cron()` you should check if the flag is set or not. If set clear Boost cache using [boost_cache_clear_all()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!boost!boost.module/function/boost_cache_clear_all/6). Unset the flag once cache is cleared.

Comment: But I don't want to clear all the boost cache files. I want to mark some files for deletion.